# vim creates copies of my files after saving?

Tags: vim

HI there,

Using vim and whenever I make a change and save a file vim seems to create a backup file. I can see that it's the file before I made my change and saved.
How can I prevent this or hide these files?

I type ***:wq*** to save and quit.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add [`set nobackup`](http://lena.franken.de/linux/vim.html) to your `~/.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 8):

Yeak, preferably you should set sth like :

```
set backupdir=~/backup/vim
set dir=~/backup/vim/swap
set undodir=~/backup/vim/undos
set undofile
set bk
```

Note also the [savevers](https://github.com/vim-scripts/savevers.vim) plugin.

So you'll never have files in places you don't want, but keep the backup functionnality.

Comment: Vim never ceases to amaze me. :) Thanks for new knowledge.