# Can I recover my code lost during my last change in vim?

Tags: linux, vim

I am very sad I deleted wrong function without commit to SVN server by using vim
After I compiled it I found I made the mistake. I 'make' the file also via vim.

Now I haven't closed the file and it has .swp file. 
I tried to use 'u' command to restore my deletion but failed. vim said it's the latest changes. sigh.... Anyway I can restore my function?

Million thanks.

Comment: I think this question is a better fit on SuperUser.com, because it's question about the features of a text editor rather than a programming question. Hope you get your code back!

Comment: @razlebe: vi, vim, and emacs are edge cases.  A question on how to use them would almost certainly survive on Super User, but since they're commonly used programming tools they're okay to ask here too.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su backs up @Bill on this.

Comment: oh... i did something wrong here after I checked revision. sorry guys, I didn't note that. Anyway, I think it's very important for C++ programmers to know how to recover last change after compiling the source code. It's not editor problem I think.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard Fair enough - thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Randy Morris - Thanks - hadn't seen that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To make Drasils pointer a lot more explicit:

```
 :undolist
```

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> to 'go back in time'

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> to 'go forward in time'

Vim 7.3+ has undo 'branches': meaning that it will save state snapshots, even if linear history was overwritten (so it isn't reachable by simple <kbd>u</kbd> and )

Comment: Life saver! undo/redo skips some changes, but not this commands!

Comment: All I get is "Nothing to undo".

Comment: @LuísdeSousa That's the message you get when there is no undo information. I would enable persistent undo, Also look at https://github.com/mbbill/undotree - although it will not show any changes not recorded, either

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of ways to recover text that you may have unwittingly lost due to a crash or because you closed your program unintentionally.

1. Use persistent-undo. Persistent undo provides almost all the features provided by swap/backup file option in points #2 and #3, along with some other options such as granular history traversal.

   a. Set `persistent-undo` on:

   Put this in your `.vimrc`:

   `set undofile`
   `set undodir=~/.vim/undodir`

   b. Create the undodir

   `mkdir ~/.vim/undodir`

   c. To undo a change, use either of the following options

   1)  `g+` in normal mode to go forward in history

   2)   `g-` in normal mode to go backward in history

   3).  `:earlier 20s` to go back in time by 20s or `earlier 10m` to go back in time by 10min etc

   4)   `:later 20s` to go forward in time by 20s or `later 10m` to go forward in time by 10min etc

   5).  Use `:undolist` to get a list of undo changes

   d. To get a visualization of your undo-branches, you can use plugins like `gundo.vim`: http://bitbucket.org/sjl/gundo.vim/ to visualize the branches
2. Use backup files

   a. Use this in your `.vimrc`
   `set backup`

   b. Set up the backup directory by putting this in your `.vimrc`
   `set backupdir=~/tmp/`

   c. Set up the backup file name to be added to the backup file by setting this in your `.vimrc`
   `set backupext=string`
3. Use swap files

   a. Use this in your `.vimrc`
   `set swapfile`

   b. Set up the swap directory by putting this in your `.vimrc`. This may not be a good idea, because it will prevent you from having two files with the same names, or cause conflicts in swap file names.

   `set directory=~/tmp/`

   A better option is to provide multiple paths, so if vim encounters a conflict it can then save it to the directory that it can write to using

   `set directory=,~/tmp/`

   In this case, it will try to write the swap file to the current directory. If it can't, then it will attempt to write it to the `~/tmp` directory

   c. Set up the backup file name to be added to the backup file by setting this in your `.vimrc`

   `set backupext=string`

**TL;DR** Use `persistent-undo`. It provides almost all features of `swap` and `backup`, and provides additional features such as granular undo which is not provided by `backup` and `swap` file options.

**References**
1. ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/doc/book/vimbook-OPL.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Vim usually saves the previous version of any file edited as a backup with a `~` appended -- you could check to see whether that file is there and if so, whether it's got the right contents.

Comment: hi, do you mean .swp file under linux? I tried vim -r .file.swp     the file is the save with my current source code.

Comment: No, I mean that if you edit `foo.c` then vim will often create `foo.c~` too.  It sounds like you don't have the right options set to create these files (`set backup` in your .vimrc).

Comment: He could check settings by doing `:echo &backup`, which will be 1 if set.  Then `:echo &backupdir` would show what directory it's set to save backups in.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can recover something here, but for the future, if you user vim 7.3, you should active these options I explain in [my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065226/vim-creates-copies-of-my-files-after-saving/5066247#5066247).

I must say that the [savevers](https://github.com/vim-scripts/savevers.vim) plugin has saved me a lot of hours ;-)

Comment: Why persistent undo + some VCS (+ regular backup) is not enough for you? After persistent undo feature was added to vim I never ran into situations like «I want to roll back a change that I made some time ago but required info is already lost» (in fact, most of time I use VCS for this job. Vim undo is used only for huge and highly unstable (and thus uncommitted) changes (or for very small chunks that can be reverted manually), persistence is needed mostly for the same reason as backups (unless I want to restart vim) and is used just as rarely).

Comment: agree with @ZyX. `persistent-undo` is great for changes that you made to the text, and may want to go back to. If you have `persistent-undo` on, you maynot even need the `swap` file options. I just mistakenly pressed `qall` and thought that I had lost a bunch of code. Then I realized that I had persistent undo on, and decided to check if it was present. Magically I was able to get back to the last version by using `earlier 30s`.

Comment: Persistent undo is better than the `swap` file option, because it doesnt put lots of swap files to your directory. It provides almost everything that the `swap` file option, because it does almost everything that the swap file option provides but also lets you go back in history in granular changes without corrupting your directory with lots of .swp files

Comment: @alpha_989 Persistent undo does put undo files in the same directory swap feature puts swap files *by default* in Vim. If you do not see that with persistent undo, but do with swap files it merely means you have configured one, but not the other. Many users (me included) configure Vim to put undo/swap/backup files elsewhere, and using separate directories under ~/.local/share/nvim for those files (minus backup) is the default in Neovim as well.

Comment: @ZyX, Yeah.. I have turned swap/backup files off. It used to frequently cause conflicts. I only use `persistent-undo` and have it configured to save in a specific undo directory. Since you use `swap`, `backup` and `persistent-undo`, I am wondering if you see area that `persistent-undo` doesnt cover, for which you use _backup/swap_ files?

Comment: @alpha_989 Backup files are just backup, not really need them, but they eat not too much space to not keep. Swap files warn about me opening the same file in another Vim: I can have lots of instances open and that does happen.